# Check for the existence of a member function fails

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03

I have some old codebase that still uses C++03. I am trying to write a template that evaluates to true if a class has a member function called `some_function`, to be used inside `enable_if` statements. I cannot make my example work, i.e. the output is always zero. Can anyone spot the error and explain why this fails, and how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T >
struct has_some_function
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];
    template< typename C > static yes& test(typename C::some_function*);
    template< typename C > static no& test(...);
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test< T >(0)) == sizeof(yes));
};

struct Test
{
    void some_function()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_some_function< Test >::value << std::endl;
}
```

With

```
g++ -std=c++03 test.cpp
```

I get

```
0
```

Comment: With `typename C::some_function`, you expect a **type**.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function) help?

Comment: Ok I found a solution, now I need to understand why it works. But this was helpful, thanks. Should I delete the question or add a solution? Seems it's been deleted anyways.

Comment: @hochl Not deleted; closed as a duplicate.